# Why does an Angular controller that is a function work, but a controller in a package does not?

Tags: angularjs

In a recent question, I was having an issue with a simple modal dialog implemented using [Angular UI for Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I started with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/), and the person who answered came up with [this result.](http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/2/)

However, one thing immediately caught my attention!

**Old Controller Implementation**

```
var controllers = angular.module('app.controllers', []);    

controllers.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', '$modal', '$log',
  function ($scope, $modal, $log) {
    // Overarching controller code...
  }
]);

controllers.controller('ModalInstanceController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 
  function ($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
    // ...Modal Instance Code...
  }
]);
```

This code *does not work* with the Angular UI for Bootstrap Modal, but for some reason, this code does:

```
var ModalController = function($scope, $modal, $log) {
  // Overarching controller code...
};

var ModalInstanceController = function($scope, $modalInstance, params) {
  // Modal Instance Code...
};
```

...The problem being, that AngularJS code is usually modularized like the first example to avoid cluttering the global namespace.

So far none of my experiments have been able to get a modularized setup to succeed in the first place.  I attempted some simple substitutions, where I would make one controller or the other be a modularized controller, in hopes that it was only one controller preventing the `params` from being passed between controllers; this turned out not to be the case.  Implementing `$scope.params = [];` before declaring the `$scope.open()` function, and populating `$scope.params` in the `open` function similarly had no effect.

**Question:** In the context of the AngularUI for Bootstrap system, why does the modularized approach fail?  And more importantly, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed plnkr (http://jsfiddle.net/pEmXt/4/), it had several problems:

- You defined your modules in the wrong order.
- You had the ui DI in the wrong place.
- Your resolve syntax was wrong.
- The DI in your modal instance controller was missing an item in the list of dependencies.

The resolve method is used like this:

```
resolve: {
  objectName: function(){
    return myObject;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer.  I'm a newcomer to Angular and the Angular ecosystem, this helped *a lot*.

Answer (score 2):

OK...so I recently ran into same issue and was perplexed also. I just never bothered to dig into it. A quick trip to angular-ui github repo and I found out in the issue tracker.

Angular-Ui demos are passing a function reference as controller. For a modular controller it needs to be a string

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
  templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
  controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl', /* use string for modular controller */
   /* OR */
    controller: ModalInstanceCtrl, /* use reference for controller as function*/

});
```

Issue tracker reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/2330

Working demo from issue tracker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/38vBcPalBBNMgYis4cZX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, the module `'app.controllers'` has to be added to the list of dependencies for the main app.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['app.controllers']);
```

In the second instance the controllers are global functions and therefore are visible without being explicitly added as a dependency.